# unknown cmake command when trying to compile stp

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, stp

An unknown cmake command error happened when I tried to compile stp on ubuntu 13( x64).
The detailed error information is `Unknown CMake command "stp_add_public_header".`

The version of cmake is 2.8.10.1. 
Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong here?
Thanks.

Comment: Where did you get stp distribution? Is it git HEAD?

Comment: I downloaded the zip file from http://stp.github.io/stp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same problem and found the cause to be that I used the wrong source directory (stp/src instead of just stp) in the call of cmake from within my build directory:

```
cmake -G 'Unix Makefiles' ../stp/src
```

instead of just

```
cmake -G 'Unix Makefiles' ../stp
```

The former gives the error, the latter works fine, because the CMakeLists.txt including the stp_add_public_header command is located in /stp.

Maybe, like me, you were mislead by the INSTALL file in which it says:

cmake -G 'Unix Makefiles' /path/to/stp/source/root

which is NOT referring to stp/src, but to stp.